# Toastr to use Laravel session variables as alert messages

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5, toastr

I am wanting to swap from `Bootstrap` alerts to `Toastr` alerts. My current working set up is:

```
@if (Session::has('flash_notification.message'))

     <div class="alert alert-{{ Session::get('flash_notification.level') }}">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" 
             aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
         {{ Session::get('flash_notification.message') }}
     </div>

 @endif
```

But I'm now struggling on accessing Laravel's session variables within JS.

The actual JS working example is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    toastr.info('Page Loaded!');

    });

});
```

But, I want to use Laravel's session variables to include different messages and warning boxes:

```
@if (Session::has('flash_notification.message'))

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            toastr.options.timeOut = 4000;
            toastr.{{ Session::get('flash_notification.level') }}('{{ Session::get('flash_notification.message) }}');

        });
    </script>

@endif
```

I'm getting various errors such as `unexpected ;`. Any help would be hugely appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are working in a blade-template you can output the content of a variable/function with `{{ var/function() }}`. If you want unescaped output you can use `{!! var/function() !!}`.

So the solution for your problem is, that you need to surround your php code with the `{{ }}` tags:

```
@if (Session::has('flash_notification.message'))

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

        toastr.{{ Session::get('flash_notification.level') }}
        ('{{ Session::get('flash_notification.message') }}');

        });
    </script>

@endif
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it returns the error `unexpected ;`

Comment: Because it's within my template.blade.php, the error message is pretty poor - `FatalErrorException in 97a837778d688883db99bfdf8c10c794 line 66: syntax error, unexpected ';'`. Line 66 is: `toastr.{{ Session::get('flash_notification.level') }}('{{ Session::get('flash_notification.message) }}');`

Comment: `Session::get('flash_notification.message)` - you are missing the second `'` after `flash_notification.message`.

Comment: Very true! I've just noticed that myself - Thank you. I'll go and check it out now.

Comment: It all appears correct, however now the error is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. The jQuery is called in the footer, but the `document.ready` should stop this error?

Comment: $ is a jQuery instance. It looks like you haven't jQuery loaded at the point your script gets called.

Comment: I put jQuery into the head of the body, not the footer, and it works correctly. Many thanks.